# Consider undeleting answer to UK ability to intervene on LGBT rights in chechenya

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

As I was running through our highest rated unanswered questions, I stumbled across this one

[What can the UK government do to help resolve the persecution of the LGBT community in Chechnya?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18361/what-can-the-uk-government-do-to-help-resolve-the-persecution-of-the-lgbt-commun)

Which seems to have a perfectly valid answer, with several upvotes. I looked through the revision history and noticed some vandalism had taken place, but had been reversed quickly. I noticed the answer is also temporarily suspended (with a suspension running out in two days).

I wish to make the case to un-delete the answer as it is informative, and we don't have a serious case to keep it deleted (as an effort against vandalism). It is worth noting that this could be done to coincide with the lifting of the author suspension in two days.

Is there any other outstanding reason why this answer should remain deleted?

Comment: Same user, same issue as in that other meta question.

Comment: Indeed it seems to be the same user/same problem - but I would still like the answer to be considered for undeletion.

Comment: Vandalism wasn't the only issue there, I'm afraid. Portions of the answer are plagiarised (eg from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay_concentration_camps_in_Chechnya). If the answer is updated to properly reference its sources (see: https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), then I'd certainly consider restoring it.

Comment: Oh the irony :-D  I delete it and get banned but Mods have to delete it anyway.

Comment: @Venture2099 Stop being a petulant child and vandalizing everything

Comment: My answers.  My right to delete

Comment: @Venture2099 You have a right to delete but not vandalise. If you wish to delete please [delete](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/how-can-i-delete-my-own-answer) not vandalise.

Comment: No. They are all plagiarised. Mods have been quite clear.  Its not vandalism.

Comment: @Venture2099 Do you not understand how this site works? If your answer was plagiarized and you wish to remove it from the site you should **delete** the answer not vandalize it

Comment: *yawn*   Stop rolling back my answers. Write your own.

Comment: Actually no the content you create belongs to SE once you submit it...

Comment: Though actually in this case I think I am on Venture's side.  The edit was not vandalism since it was clearly indicated why the content was removed.  Its not like he changed it to post "I hate the Mods here!"  It stated why the content was removed by the person who created the original answer.