# How can I influence high quality answer undelete?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I have stumbled across [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18361/what-can-the-uk-government-do-to-help-resolve-the-persecution-of-the-lgbt-commun/18362#18362) and [this removed answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/18362/11278) (visible to 2K+ users only).

[Revisions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/18362/revisions) indicate that the author chose to vandalize its own answer instead of just removing it and a moderator hammered the answer afterwards (probably related to user's suspension). However, another user decided (correctly from my point of view) to rollback what it looks like a good answer.

Unfortunately, the answer still remains deleted (thus invisible to most users).

**Question:** Is there a way to undelete this answer (and similar ones)?

Or this is not an accepted act within the community when the user is currently suspended and cannot have an input on this matter.

**Edit**

Although this question deals with a question affected by the same phenomenon as that indicated by the so called duplicate, it is different. This asks about how to resurrect such an answer (high quality, vandalized, rolled back, but still deleted), not why it ended being removed.

Comment: Same as [this](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3016/11249) and [this](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3041/11249). Same author of the answer.

Comment: I think I made a mistake by rolling back the "vandalism", by the way. It's only confusing people. Sorry 'bout that :-(

Answer (score 3):

A few of that user's answers got deleted for Plagiarism.  For many answers, you could copy and paste large sections of paragraphs into google and find the source that he copied from without proper attribution.

This user got upset and threw a tantrum where he vandalized all of his posts.  We Reverted the vandalism, but haven't yet inspected all of the posts for plagiarism.  The ones that have been inspected got deleted.